# syslog-ng (v 3.15.1) unable to listen on standard TCP or UDP (but can listen over TLS)

Tags: syslog-ng

Racking my brain on what I may be missing here... I upgraded to version 3.15.1 and unable to listen on TCP or UDP. Oddly enough, I am able to listen on TCP and communicate over TLS. I have read and re-read the manual (https://syslog-ng.com/documents/html/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-sources-network.html). Running on CentOS 7.

Here is relevant portions of my config:

```
...
# never listens and have tried using udp() and tcp() sources as 
# well as breaking each out to their individual source defs 
source s_net {
       network(ip(0.0.0.0) port(6514) transport("tcp"));
       network(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514) transport("udp"));
};

# works perfectly
source s_net_tls {
    network(
        ip(0.0.0.0)
        port(22514)
        transport("tls")
        tls(
            key-file('/path/to/foo.key')
            cert-file('/path/to/foo.pem')
            peer-verify(optional-untrusted)
            ssl-options(no-sslv2, no-sslv3, no-tlsv1)
        )
    );
};
...
```

Output of netstat:

```
$ netstat -tulna | grep -e 514 -e 6514 -e 22514
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22514           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
$
```

Here is the stdout:

```
$ sudo syslog-ng -Fedv; syslog-ng-ctl verbose --set=on && syslog-ng-ctl trace --set=on && syslog-ng-ctl debug --set=on
... [ OMITTING UNNECESSARY LINES ] ...
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406200] Reading shared object for a candidate module; path='/usr/local/lib/syslog-ng', fname='libafsocket.so', module='afsocket'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406363] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='source', name='unix-stream'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406371] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='destination', name='unix-stream'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406375] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='source', name='unix-dgram'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406421] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='destination', name='unix-dgram'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406427] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='source', name='tcp'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406432] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='destination', name='tcp'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406440] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='source', name='tcp6'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406444] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='destination', name='tcp6'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406448] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='source', name='udp'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406452] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='destination', name='udp'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406456] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='source', name='udp6'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406460] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='destination', name='udp6'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406464] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='source', name='syslog'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406468] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='destination', name='syslog'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406474] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='source', name='network'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406478] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='destination', name='network'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.406482] Registering candidate plugin; module='afsocket', context='source', name='systemd-syslog'
... [ OMITTING UNNECESSARY LINES ] ...
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.409282] Registering candidate plugin; module='basicfuncs', context='template-func', name='ipv4-to-int'
... [ OMITTING UNNECESSARY LINES ] ...
**[2018-06-23T20:46:47.438730] Accepting connections; addr='AF_INET(0.0.0.0:22514)'**
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.439056] Module loaded and initialized successfully; module='linux-kmsg-format'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.439307] Running application hooks; hook='1'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.439315] Running application hooks; hook='3'
[2018-06-23T20:46:47.439328] syslog-ng starting up; version='3.15.1'
```

I am not new to syslog-ng and hoping it's something simple I have overlooked - Hoping a few more eyes find what mine are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was although I defined the source driver, I had overlooked it not be referenced in the defined log path. I had been bouncing back and forth through too many configs and somehow missed creating the reference for the input source. It's working now.

```
...
log {
    source(s_net);
    ...
}
```

Output of netstat:

```
$ netstat -tulna | grep -e 514 -e 6514 -e 22514
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22514           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6514            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*       
$
```